# Codeception disabling extensions on runtime

Tags: php, codeception

Codeception disabling extensions on runtime

I am having a problem with two custom extensions that I have to comment out when I run Gherkin tests. I was thinking, Is there a way to add a flag in the run command where I can disable the extensions?

```
#Codeception.yml
extensions:
    enabled:
        - CustomExt1
        - CustomExt2
```

Was thinking of something like

```
$ codecept run suite —disable-ext CustomExt1 CustomExt2
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to use the command line flag to enable or disable modules is the suite itself. In other words, selecting the suite IS the flag. There is no built in functionality to do this, creating a separate suite that doesn't include the module you want to disable is the way to go.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18786372)

Comment: Yes it does answer the question. :) Codeception configs are very complicated. You have a better answer? If you want to downvote, please explain your reason.

Comment: this would be better said as a comment.

Comment: I agree, this is the answer: if you want different configs you need a different suite which is configured differently.